# Update MySQL database using JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp

Umm, hello guys. I'm trying to create JSP files that update a MySQL database, it works "without errors" but only shows a white screen and doesn't update the database. Here are the JSPs that I use:

profiletest.jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 String database = "sais2";
 String userid = "root";
 String password = "";
 try {
 Class.forName(driver);
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 Connection connection = null;
 Statement statement = null;
 ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Profile</title>
 </head>
 <jsp:include page="head.jsp"></jsp:include>
 <body onload="startTime()" style="background-image:url(assets/img/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment:fixed;background-size:cover">
  <jsp:include page="header1.jsp"></jsp:include>
  <jsp:include page="settings-nav.jsp"></jsp:include>
  <table border="1" width="75%" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">ID</td>
    <td align="center">First Name</td>
    <td align="center">Last Name</td>
    <td align="center">E-Mail</td>
    <td align="center">Update</td>
   </tr>
<%
try{
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
 statement=connection.createStatement();
 String sql ="SELECT * FROM login";
 resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
 while(resultSet.next()){
%>
   <tr>
    <td align="center"><%=resultSet.getString("id") %></td>
    <td align="center"><%=resultSet.getString("fname") %></td>
    <td align="center"><%=resultSet.getString("lname") %></td>
    <td align="center"><%=resultSet.getString("email") %></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="updateprofile.jsp?id=<%=resultSet.getString("id")%>">UPDATE</a></td>
   </tr>
<%
 } 
 connection.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

updateprofile.jsp

```html
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sais2";
 String userid = "root";
 String password = "";
 try {
  Class.forName(driver);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 Connection connection = null;
 Statement statement = null;
 ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
<%
 try{
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
  statement = connection.createStatement();
  String sql ="SELECT * FROM login WHERE id ="+id;
  resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
  while(resultSet.next()){
%>
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>Profile</title>
 </head>
 <jsp:include page="head.jsp"></jsp:include>
 <body onload="startTime()" style="background-image:url(assets/img/bg.jpg);
  background-attachment:fixed;background-size:cover">
  <jsp:include page="header1.jsp"></jsp:include>
  <jsp:include page="settings-nav.jsp"></jsp:include>
  <form method="post" action="update-process.jsp">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="<%=resultSet.getString("fname")%>" required/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" value="<%=resultSet.getString("lname")%>" required/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >E-Mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<%=resultSet.getString("email")%>" required/>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <input class="loginb" type="submit" value="Update"/>
  </form>
<%
  }
  connection.close();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
%>
 </body>
</html>
```

and updateprocess.jsp

```html
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%!String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";%>
<%!String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sais2";%>
<%!String userid = "root";%>
<%!String password = "";%>
<%
 String id = request.getParameter("id");
 String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
 String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
 String email = request.getParameter("email");
 if(id != null){
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  int personID = Integer.parseInt(id);
  try{
   Class.forName(driverName);
   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
   String sql = "UPDATE login SET lname = ?, fname = ?, email = ? WHERE id = " + id;
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(1, lname);
   ps.setString(2, fname);
   ps.setString(3, email);
   int i = ps.executeUpdate();
   if(i != 0){
    out.print("Record Updated Successfully");
       String redirectURL = "http://localhost:8080/SalesandInventory/System/profiletest.jsp";
       response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
   }
   else{
    out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
   }
  }
 catch(SQLException sql){
  request.setAttribute("error", sql);
  out.println(sql);
 }
}
%>
```

Can you please help me? I really can't find where is the error and I don't understand JSP that much because our professor just dropped this bomb on us with little to no knowledge.

Comment: I am suggesting to try to use MVC.Do not mix up code of view and business and model part.Separate view from business logic and database logic.

Answer (score 0):

Include one more `jsp` page and perform database operation in te second `jsp` page by forwording all values from your first page to the second page. Or Use a servlet to perform database updation.

In this same age you are not able to update `MySQL` database because `java` code is not transmitted to browser instead it is **compiled** in a **web-container** **running on the server** and then **converted** **to html code** and then transferred to the browser.

Additional Resources: [JSP Architecture](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_architecture.htm) and head over to **JSP Processing**